# redirecting to html pages using javascript,jquery,html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

hi guys um facing a problem in my assignment the assignment is to make a table that includes words edit and delete ,

once i click on delete it alerts  "are you sure you want to delete" if i pressed on it,it redirects into another html page that says " the row is successfully deleted"

another thing when i press on edit  text it redirects to another page that contains course name textbox,student name textbox ,button>edit ...

if anyone could help me because i am a beginner i'll be so thankful this is the code i wrote until now ,,, btw redirecting function is not working with me i tried many many function to redirect to another html but i couldn't solve it

[that's how the table should look like and i dont have a problem in it's xhtml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbS2d.png)

Comment: Where is this assignment from, and what have they asked you to use to produce this? I'm almost certain you haven't been asked to redirect to different pages, editing and deleting table rows (database rows for most purposes) using jquery & html. What you have asked is not possible using the tools you've listed.

Comment: Can you please provide more information of your problem?
I mean, when you want to make the redirect and where?
Would you like to use ajax or just redirect?

Comment: @jBux unfortunately those are the languages that um supposed to use  .. :)
if it could be done without redirecting to another page and just hide the elements of the current page so i'ts correct also . instructors won't reject it

Comment: @vixed  as shown in the image attached there's an edit and delete links .. when i press on delete i just want an another page.html to .open and include for example <h1 > row is deleted successfulyy </h1>

when pressing edit another page.html with the new information and an edit button .. it's not important to save the new values i just want it to complete the process successfully

Comment: @Studentprog, after your explanation, I can tell you that: just add a link to delete `<a href="delete.html">delete</a>` and another link to edit `<a href="edit.html">edit</a>` and place the **<h1>** in that pages with the message you want.

Comment: @Studentprog can you tell me what happens after the click?

Comment: @vixed ohh it worked thank youu so much . (y)

Comment: @Studentprog ahahahah thanks! But it was more easy than you can imagine, I thought you were looking for something else. Please, if I solved your problem, can you check my comment as good? PS.You can start to learn links feature from here: [w3schools href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: aha i knew it's easy that's what made me so curious to know the answer :D .. by the way i think i cant vote up for comments . it should be written in answers section . the up arrow is not showing beside your comment

Answer (score 0):

if your using native javascript you could achieve it with something like.

edit: this will now redirect to your imgur png if you choose okay in the confirm window. The same principal applies to your site. if you confirm the prompt the link whatever that may me will be followed otherwise the page will do nothing.

This code does not support IE < 9. If you wish to use a non modern browser or need to support it there are plenty of resources that will show you the alternate syntax. mdn is a great resource. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web

```js
// capture all the delete links on the page. Using a class is the easiest
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

// you can loop over the links anyway you choose. I'm using forEach
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function( link ){
  //bind the checkDeleteUser event
  link.addEventListener('click', checkDeleteUser, false);
});

function checkDeleteUser(e){
  // use the native user prompt
  if( ! confirm('are you sure you want to delete this user' ) ){
    // they said no cancel the default link behavior of redirecting
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- I'm not sure if it's clear, but you need to add a class to your anchor tags -->
<a class="delete" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbS2d.png">delete</a>
<a class="delete" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web>">go to mdn</a>
<!-- <a class="delete" href="/delete-page.php?userId=69">delete</a> -->
```

Comment: it doesn't redirect to another page its not even showing up the confirm log

Comment: what browser are you using. this is for modern browsers only and IE9+. if you want a different browser you need to hove the alternative syntax for `querySelectorAll` and addEventListener` if you click 'Run code snippet' above you will see it working on that iframe.

If you are removing someone from a database you will be doing it in php and sending a get param to the server that you can use to identify the user.

Personally I would use ajax to send the request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

After your explanation in comments, I can tell you that: just add a link to **delete**

```
 `<a href="delete.html">delete</a>`
```

and another link to **edit**

```
<a href="edit.html">edit</a>
```

and place the **h1** in that pages with the message you want